# Hadoop context.write() buffer size

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, hbase

I am using `context.write()` with puts to write to HBase from Mapper. 
According to this [mailing list](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.java.hadoop.hbase.user/47414), `context.write()` doesn't flush right away and waits for the buffer to be full before they are set asynchronously to the server.

How does one set the buffer size of Mapper output. Intention is to reduce the RPC calls to HBase table by adjusting the buffer size.

Answer (score 0):

HBase client side buffer can be configured by parameter hbase.client.write.buffer

Apart from increasing client side buffer you can also look at  this [reference](http://hbase.apache.org/0.94/book/perf.writing.html) for optimising writes to hbase.